# Nested REST resources in the appropriate bounded context module

Tags: nestjs

I am struggling to place a REST route resolver in what I think is the right module.

I have:

- A `UserModule` with a controller that handles the `/users` routes.
- A `AdModule` with a controller that handles the `/ads` routes.

I am attempting to model the resource `/users/:id/ads` to return all the ads from an user.

This route is pending on the `/users` resource. I can make it work by creating the logic in the `UserModule` and importing the service from `AdModule`. That works but does not seem the right place for that code. As the entity handled is `Ad` and I would prefer it being handled by the `AdModule`. This is how I modeled it in GraphQL APIs with NestJS.

The other option would be creating a new controller only for this, as the @Controller decorator seems to be a jail that I can not escape with @Get.

Is there a known way to address this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new controller in the `AdModule` without any route prefix decorator. That allowed me to place the code in the place that I expect it without any downside so far.